# What is the fraction at the end of datetimes in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec, rspec-rails

I was doing some testing with rSpec, when I wanted to test if a job gets queued at the correct time. For that I queued the task at `2.hours.from_now` and then checked it with `.at(2.hours.from_now)`. I quickly realised my mistake and changed that to a variable which fixed the test, but I realised that the test checked for `at xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx 721891/1048576 +xxxx`. Now I am left wondering what the `721891/1048576` exactly does. I found out that `1048576 byte` are one `Mebibyte`. Is it possible that the fraction at the end simply is further precision of the moment, but instead of `x/1048576` it shows `1048576` due to the precision being `2^20`?
Additional information: The used db is psql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be the way [`Time#inspect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Time.html#inspect-method) works if the fractional (decimal) part of the subsecond is longer than 9 digits:

```rb
Time.new(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1/1_000_000_000r, 'UTC')
#=> 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000000001 UTC

Time.new(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1/10_000_000_000r, 'UTC')
#=> 2022-01-01 00:00:00 1/10000000000 UTC
```

or if it doesn't have a (finite) decimal representation:

```rb
Time.new(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2/3r, 'UTC')
#=> 2022-01-01 00:00:00 2/3 UTC
```

> Now I am left wondering what the 721891/1048576 exactly does.

Your `721891/1048576` is equivalent to ~0.688 seconds, it doesn't have any other special meaning.

The rational number could be the result of passing the time's floating point representation back to [`Time.at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Time.html#at-method):

```rb
t = Time.at(1640995200, 688449)
#=> 2022-01-01 01:00:00.688449 +0100

t.to_f
#=> 1640995200.688449

Time.at(1640995200.688449)
#=> 2022-01-01 01:00:00 721891/1048576 +0100
```

This is a common mistake when working with subseconds in Ruby.

Comment: But if you look at it, the fraction is x/1_048_576, which is a subsecond of 7 digits. And why is the denominator 2^20?

Comment: @Anes the fraction is your example is 721891/1048576. Its decimal form is 0.68844890594482421875, which has more than 7 digits.